# NoClassDefFoundError when using RoboSpice's OkHttpBitmapSpiceManager to load image from URL

Tags: android, asynchronous, noclassdeffounderror, robospice

I'm creating an Android application which uses RoboSpice for asynchronous network calls. Although I have no experience with RoboSpice, I've chosen for RoboSpice as it's regarded as one of the best on the internet, and because it can automatically convert JSON to POJO's. Unfortunately, the quality of the documentation of RoboSpice is a bit poor. Therefore my question:

I've succesfully used RoboSpice to make a network call to a REST GET method, automatically parse the JSON to a POJO and show the list of retrieved objects in an Android ViewPager. I'm using *Jackson2GoogleHttpClientSpiceService* to do this. Now, in this ViewPager I'm showing an image as well. Obviously, I want to download this image using RoboSpice. I've used one of the [RoboSpice examples](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-ui-spicelist) (which uses the OkHttpBitmapSpiceManager to download an image) as a guide and according to that I've added this line to my activity:

```
private OkHttpBitmapSpiceManager spiceManagerBinary = new OkHttpBitmapSpiceManager();
```

Also, I've added this line to the manifest:

```
<service
        android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.spicelist.okhttp.OkHttpBitmapSpiceService"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Now, as I'm not using maven for my Android project, I had to add the following jar to my project: *robospice-ui-spicelist-1.4.9.jar* (I've obviously added all the other necessary jar's for using the *Jackson2GoogleHttpClientSpiceService*, which works).

The problem is, the application fails to even start. Whenever I remove (or comment) the line containing the `new OkHttpBitmapSpiceManager()` the application works flawlessly. So apparently calling the constructor is what makes the application crash. I get the following error from the logcat:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.octo.android.robospice.spicelist.okhttp.OkHttpBitmapSpiceService
```

To me, this error seems to relate to a missing jar or something. But I've added all the necessary jar's according to the documentation. Can someone with experience of RoboSpice explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? Should I add more jar's or am I missing something else? Or should I even use a completely different approach to loading images from a URL using RoboSpice?

---

**EDIT!**

To make it more clear, I've added the following jar's to my libs folder and the build path:

- commons-io-1.3.2.jar
- commons-lang3-3.1.jar
- google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
- google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar
- google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc.jar
- guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
- jsr305-1.3.9.jar
- robospice-1.4.9.jar
- robospice-cache-1.4.9.jar
- robospice-google-http-client-1.4.9.jar
- robospice-ui-spicelist-1.4.9.jar

Comment: Are the JARs in your `libs` (with an `s`) folder?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the libs folder and I have added them to the classpath using Build Path -> Add to Build Path in Eclipse.

Comment: I think the OkHttpBitmapSpiceService class is present in one of the robospice jars. Make sure you have added those jars in classpath. You can debug further by following this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using a jar that contains the service class : `com.octo.android.robospice.spicelist.okhttp.OkHttpBitmapSpiceService`.

It is not contained in robospice-ui-spice-list but in [robospice-okhttp](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.octo.android.robospice%22%20AND%20a%3A%22robospice-okhttp%22). If you include this jar, you will get the service you need.

Have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-okhttpclient).

Also, please not that to download an image, it can be even easier to use non okhttp related classes. RS offers simple binary requests in [its core package](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/tree/release/robospice-core-parent/robospice/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/request/simple).

Oh, and btw, when you say "RS docs is a bit poor", please let us now via github or the mailing list how you would like to see it more complete. We also accept pull requests, even only for documentation.

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the problem. However, if I look at the "Setup for Non Maven users" section in the RoboSpice Wiki, there is no mention about having to add that jar for the SpiceList Module (or any other module). That's what makes the RoboSpice documentation 'a bit poor' for new users (this was not intended to to be disrespectful).
I've tried your simple approach, using SpiceRequest<Bitmap>. However, I only get back a Bitmap in the listener, which is nice, but as I'm using a ViewPager there is no way of telling which Bitmap belongs to which view in the pager. Any solutions to that?

Comment: Give an index to your listeners, the index of the page in the view pager. That's it. For the documentation, I will check this. Would you mind to fill an issue refering to this Stack Over Flow Thread on our github repo ? Don't worry about having been disrespectful, you were not. Thanks for the feedback on RS. Oh, and if the answer matches, please accept it for next users.

Comment: Of course, stupid that I didn't think of such a solution. Thanks for all the help. I'm having another problem (related to RoboSpice) but I will post that in another question. Tomorrow I will fill an issue on the RoboSpice Github repo and I just accepted your answer!